How to implement variable electromagnet control?
I'm planning to build a small model engine dynamometer, of the eddy current type. Basically the engine spins a metal disk, and the stator contains some electromagnets, which will induce a current on the disk. The current creates a electromagnetic resistance, trying to stop the relative movement between disk and stator.
To measure the engine torque at various RPMs, it is necessary to vary the force of the electromagnets, otherwise you just stall the engine.
What is the best way to vary the force on the electromagnets? PWM?
The magnets I'm probably going to use are 12v 5kg (50N force). The engine runs will be short, maybe around 10s or so, there's no prolonged use.

The electromagnets are power hungry.
So pwm (efficient) is more suitable than linear voltage control.
You can also buy a variable buck converter with potentiometer for few $. It’s the same.
If you need to control voltage electronically (instead pot) you can rebuild the converter feedback.
